# Playing music in the car with the windows open

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, music, vehicles-transportation, loud-quiet

Shmuel is playing music in car. He decides to crank up the volume and opens his windows so that rest of society can hear the music.

Is this forbidden, *halachically*? Even if it is permitted, is there any other reason *not* to do it?

Comment: Dina demalchusa

Comment: Please edit in your reason for suspecting that such a concept exists in Halacha.